# webview.postUrl(String url, byte[] postData) not working for Android 11 and above?

Tags: java, android, webview, android-11, postdata

I am trying to load data in my webview and with the method:

```
webview.postUrl(url, byteData)
```

I am able to get correctly filled form data in webview but for Android OS 11 and above it is loading plain form with no data filled.

Comment: Did you add this line in application tag in Manifest ? 
 android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Comment: Yes, @AhmedElsayed that is being used